# Get all Rows with two Date Columns where Dates are in or between an specified intervall

Tags: sql, date, time, intervals

I recently had this problem and was wondering if I took the right way.
Think of a table that has two Columns with dates, one stands for the start of something and the other one is the ending of something.
Lets call them **VALID_FROM** and **VALID_TO**. As Input you give it **START** and **END**.
In the picture the first "line" is representing a timeline, whatever line would cross the box is seem as valid data.
The underlying lines are possible date constellations, while the left end of the line is always **VALID_FROM** and the right one is always **VALID_TO**.
Ends a line with a Diamond has this Column a fixxed Date, if not its until infinity (you can think here of a null value).

[image: Timeline Illustration]

The approach i now took was to check for six cases:

1. from infinity to infity:

- **VALID_FROM** = null and **VALID_TO** = null

2. from infinity to fixed **VALID_TO**:

- **VALID_FROM** = null and **VALID_TO** >= **START**

3. from fixed **VALID_FROM** to infinity:

- **VALID_TO** = null and **VALID_FROM** <= **END**

4. **VALID_FROM** is smaller than **START**,so **VALID_TO** must be bigger than **START**:

- **VALID_FROM** <= **START** and **VALID_TO** > **START**

5. **VALID_TO** is bigger than **END**, so **VALID_FROM** must be smaller than **END**:

- **VALID_FROM** >= **END** and **VALID_TO** < **END**

6. **VALID_FROM** and **VALID_TO** is between **START** and **END**

- **VALID_FROM** >= **START** and **VALID_TO** <= **END**

If you need any information let me know. Do you think the my possible constellations are complete?
If you have any idea just share your thoughts i would be interested in it.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results *as text tables* would be a big help -- and a db/sql fiddle is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a simple filter:

```
select t.*
from t
where valid_to > :start and
      valid_from < :end
```

That is two time intervals overlap if the first ends *after* the second starts, and the first starts *before* the second ends.

Your terminology suggests that you want an actual overlap and not two time periods that just touch.  However, that is easily handled by changing the `<` and `>` to `<=` and `>=`.